# How to get the system clock in format in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

I want to get the system clock (time and date) and display it in a human-readable format in Perl.
The format like `2014-09-12 15:13:56`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my %months = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jun  Jul
Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov Dec);
@weekDays = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun);
($second, $minute, $hour, $dayOfMonth, $month, $yearOffset, $dayOfWeek, $dayOfYear,   
$daylightSavings) = localtime();
$year = 1900 + $yearOffset;
$now = "$year-$months-$dayOfMonth $hour:$minute:$second";
print $now;
```

When you run the program, you should see a much more readable date and time like this:

```
2014--12 16:57:15
```

how to get convert the month to number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier using a Perl module (POSIX doesn't requires installation):

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
my $now_string = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime;
print $now_string, "\n"; #<-- prints: 2014-09-12 11:09:45 (with my local time)
```

Regarding to your code, there is a typo:

```
$now = "$year-$months-$dayOfMonth $hour:$minute:$second";
```

should be:

```
$now = "$year-$month-$dayOfMonth $hour:$minute:$second";
```

Be sure to write `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in the top place of your script. It prevents you from errors like that.

Comment: `POSIX::strftime()` is indeed the standard solution to this

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) (core module since perl `v5.9.5`)

```
use Time::Piece;
my $dt = localtime;
print $dt->ymd, " ", $dt->hms, "\n";
```

using [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now();
print $dt->ymd, " ", $dt->hms, "\n";
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that Time::Piece is included as standard with modern Perl distributions. DateTime isn't (but I strongly recommend installing it).

Answer (score 0):

I like to put these date and time tasks into functions for reuse. 
Here is my approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $time_stamp = getTodaysDateTime();
print "Program Started: $time_stamp \n";

# do some processing 

$time_stamp = getTodaysDateTime();
print "Program Ended: $time_stamp \n";


# return date in specific format 
# ex: 2014-09-12 14:11:43
sub getTodaysDateTime {
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,
        $wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
    $year += 1900;
    $mon += 1;
    return sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        $year,$mon,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
}
```